# Makefiles: using `wildcard` vs. `find` for specifying source files

Tags: makefile, find, wildcard

**TL;DR:** How can I use `find` in a `Makefile` in order to identify the relevant source files (e.g., all `.c` files)?  I know how to use a `wildcard` but I'm not able to get `find` to work.

**Longer version:**
I'm putting together a `Makefile` as part of an exercise on shared libraries; I noticed that when I use the following lines to specify the source and object files (i.e., `.c` files) for my shared library, I get an error after running `make` (`gcc fatal error: no input files`):

```
SRC=$(find src/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex ".*\.c")
OBJ=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC))
*rest-of-makefile*
```

However, it compiles correctly when I use `wildcard` instead of `find`:

```
SRC=$(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJ=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC))
*rest-of-makefile*
```

(As reference, included below is confirmation that the `find` command does indeed return the intended file when run from the shell.)

What is the correct syntax for using the `find` command (in my `Makefile`) to search for my source files (if it's at all possible)?

(Why would I prefer to use find?: I like the fact that I can quickly double-check the results of a `find` statement by running the command from the shell; I can't do that with `wildcard`.  Also, I'd like to rely on regexes if possible. )

---

As reference, below is the relevant tree structure.  As you can see (from the second code-block below), running the `find` command as specified in the Makefile (i.e., from above) does indeed return the intended file (`src/libex29.c`).  In other words, the issue described above isn't because of a syntax problem in the `find` options or the regex.

```
.
├── build
├── Makefile
├── src
│   ├── dbg.h
│   ├── libex29.c
│   └── minunit.h
└── tests
    ├── libex29_tests.c
    └── runtests.sh
```

Results of running `find` from the `.` folder above:

```
~/lchw30$ find src/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex ".*\.c"
src/libex29.c
```

P.S. I know this post technically violates the rule that `all posted code must compile` - I just thought that including the entire code for the both the `Makefile` as well as the `libex29.c` source file would be overkill.  Let me know if that's not the case - happy to post the files in their entirety, if folks prefer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make doesn't have a `find` function.  You have to use the `shell` function to run find.  Also you should always use `:=` not `=` for `shell` (and `wildcard`, for that matter) for performance reasons.  And you should put spaces around assignments in make, just for clarity:

```
SRC := $(shell find src/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex ".*\.c")
```

Also I don't see why you want to use `find` here.  `find` is good if you want to search and entire subdirectory structure which contains more than one level, but `wildcard` is far more efficient for simple directory lookups.

Comment: This is great, thanks.  Appreciate the suggestions re: clarity/performance.  One quick follow-up question: is there anyway to run `wildcard` (or its equivalent) in the shell?  It'd be helpful for debugging purposes...

Comment: Well, `$(wildcard *.c)` is basically the same as running `echo *.c` in the shell (except if there are no matches).  If that's what you mean.

Comment: Just wanted to mention what `wildcard` is platform-agnostic while `find` may be platform-specific. With `find`, we ended up with prerequisites being sorted differently on CI and dev machines. Took us a while to find out what was going on.

Comment: If order matters you should use `| sort` or similar after find.  It's never a good idea to rely on order of output though...

Comment: See also the documentation of the `shell` function: <https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html>